# What values for "cancel_at" and "proration behavior" on Stripe subscription for 12 equal payments, no proration?

Tags: stripe-payments

Working with the "Update subscription" call on the Stripe API.

I'm trying to replicate the behavior of a 12-month subscription with no auto-renew. (I know you can use Subscription Schedules for this, but a constraint I have is that I need to work with the original, actual Subscription and not replace it with a Schedule)

What value should I set the "cancel_at" and "proration_behavior" to ensure the customer is charged 12 equal monthly payments, and then nothing more?

(I'm afraid that if I set "cancel_at" too early, the last month won't be charged in full, or that if I set "cancel_at" too late, they will randomly be charged a few cents for a prorated 13th month)

Let's say the start date is 1692709278 (UNIX) / "August 22, 2023 1:01:18 PM".

Should I set it for "August 22, 2024 1:01:18 PM", or something slightly before? And what would I set the "proration_behavior" to? (I assume "none"?)

(Edited to fix naming of "proration_behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Susbcription Schedules would be the safest way to set iterations, however if you want to do this at Subscription-level, you're right with using `cancel_at`.

In your example, you're right in your assumption - the `cancel_at` should be August 22, 2024 1:01:18 PM -> the last Invoice your customer receives will be on July 22 2024 (assuming the Price is licenced == bills for the upcoming period).
Prorations would happen (regardless of `proration_behavior`, since these are future periods) if your date is different by any second.

> I need to work with the original, actual Subscription and not replace it with a Schedule

Schedules don't replace Subscriptions, they are a parent for it.
Creating a Schedule leads to this parenting stream:
Schedule > Subscription > Invoice > Payment
You can also append a Schedule to an existing Subscription, more info here:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#existing-subscription

Comment: Ah, interesting, okay, so in this scenario where I still have to work from creating a Subscription first, I would:

1) Create the Subscription as normal, which charges the customer for the first of 12 total payments
2) Create a Subscription Schedule with "from_subscription" as the only parameter set (to the ID of the Subscription created in step 1)
3) Update the Subscription Schedule to set it to end after 12 iterations

Comment: Exactly :) You can't set the phases right away, your Schedule needs to be blank if you append it to an existing Subscription. When you update your Schedule, you need to quote back the `start_date` and `items` set in `phase[0]` (the default phase). 
Might seem like more work, to be honest `cancel_at` is much simpler if you think you can handle the timecode calculation without any mistake, but I personally prefer schedules since timezones and daylight savings can really ruin your day with that.

Comment: Amazing! I'm 99% of the way there — on the new phase I'm creating, would I say "11" iterations (because 1 payment was already collected in the first phase), or would I say "12" iterations because I want 12 total payments? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Depends... You could just set `iterations=12` on `phases[0]`, and have only the one phase for your entire schedule (you have to quote back the `start_date` and `items` to have a common starting point, but you can change the `end_date`). OR you can end your `phases[0]` after 1 iteration, and add a new phase with 11 more. Use test clocks to advance time and confirm that your Schedule cancels when you expect it to : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks